# Event handler: currying or not?

Tags: javascript

I was working on my React project with Material-ui, and noticed a strange (?) way for writing an event handler:

https://codesandbox.io/s/8091z?file=/demo.js

In above example, the handler for checkbox is defined as:

```js
  const handleToggle = (value) => () => {
    const currentIndex = checked.indexOf(value);
    const newChecked = [...checked];

    if (currentIndex === -1) {
      newChecked.push(value);
    } else {
      newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1);
    }

    setChecked(newChecked);
  };
```

What I usually do is just:

```js
  const handleToggle = (value) => {
    const currentIndex = checked.indexOf(value);
    const newChecked = [...checked];

    if (currentIndex === -1) {
      newChecked.push(value);
    } else {
      newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1);
    }

    setChecked(newChecked);
  };
```

The result is the same. So what is the specific reason to write handlers this way?

Just for shorter code when using the function?

---

Thank guys! And sorry for not being clear...

I understand the difference of using these 2 handlers.

For the first one, I use it like `onClick={handleToggle(value)}`;

and for the second one, `onClick={() => { handleToggle(value) }}`.

Just wondering which one is preferred.

Comment: It's not the same. First one returns function in function, second one returns single function. How do you use `handleToggle`?

Comment: If you use the second approach, it will call it immediately, and uses its return value (`undefined`) as the `onClick` handler (which essentially disables it), making the code evaluate when the component is rendered, not when the `ListItem` is clicked

Comment: @Justinas They use it as an `onClick` handler in a JSX object

Comment: @Junming Wang: Based on your edit. I have answered. It depends on your choice, I personally prefer avoiding currying approach. That's a bit confusing to work with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic Issue comes up when we have to pass data as parameter to our handler.

If you try doing it the second way (the one which you refer to as normal way in your question) and have you handler as below (without any modification).

```
onClick={handleToggle(value)}
```

You will see the function will be called immediately initially and the click handler will not work afterwards. `This happens when we want to pass data to the handler parameter.`  Run the snippet below, you will see method being called immediately on initial render and then handler no longer works :)

**CODE DEMO:**

```js
function App() {
  const handleClick = (value) => {
    console.log("Hello Hello");
  };
  return( <input type="checkbox" onChange={handleClick("dummy value")} />);
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

So Either go with the currying way or use the below technique  to pass data to your handler.

```
onClick={()=>handleToggle(value)}
```

This will make sure your data is passed as parameter to your event handler.

**CODE DEMO Without Currying:**

```js
    function Test() {
      const handleClick = (value) => {
        console.log(value);
      };
      return( <input type="checkbox" onChange={()=>handleClick("dummy value")} />);
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<Test/>,document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**UPDATE:** Based on the update from the OP.

The preferred approach depends on your implementation of the handler function.

1. If you want to use Currying approach in your Handler. Then you have to use

   ```
    onClick={ handleToggle(value)}
   ```
2. If you want to do it the second way then use

   ```
    onClick={() => { handleToggle(value) }}
   ```

I personally avoid the currying approach and prefer the 2nd approach :) Choice is your's.

Comment: So there's no obvious difference (like in performance or other)? Just 2 different coding styles?

Comment: No, I think when you use curry, there is a function within a function :) So an extra function being used. I feel it as an overkill ...